# Is it possible to reference C# Dependency from Kotlin?

Tags: c#, android, kotlin, maui

Our backend code is based on C# and we have an Android app based on Kotlin. The only user of the backend is this Android app (no iOS, web, etc.)

Our backend team has created a library and we are looking for a way to use it in the Kotlin project as a dependency. Is it possible?

I found that there is a technology called Maui that lets us create cross-platform projects using dotnet. Can I use this technology in my Kotlin project to use that c# library?

Comment: You don't need maui, its core is still [mono](https://github.com/mono/mono), but why not ask them to create the lib in kotlin?

Comment: No, you can't directly use C# based code with kotlin, instead you can expose your library as web API and make HTTP requests. Or If possible create a wrapper app using c# that uses your c# library. Then made your kotlin app to communicate with that wrapper app. Else you need to write the entire frontend code using C# using xamarin

Comment: @shingo, they are c# experts and not familiar with Kotlin that much. They use c# dependencies in their Lib. I'm investigating about this to find out if there is a way to do it. Thank you for your comment anyway.

Comment: @sanjay, thank you for your comment. Your second suggestion looks interesting to me. Do you know any good document that tells me how to create a wrapper app and link it to the Kotlin app?

Comment: @Hesam actually I am not much into C# for Mobile App Development, I will tell you a quick overview of how you can achieve this, for this you need a xamarin framework, you need to add kotlin app as dependency in your C# app. You need to use Java Native Interface (JNI) to invoke Kotlin code from C# in Xamarin. Handle permission in C# app manifest appropriately for kotlin app inside.

Comment: @Sanjay, Thank you my friend for your explanations. Looks very scary to me. Let me share your info with my colleagues and see what they say. I appreciate sharing your thoughts with me.